# Find special character in string and change it using Regular expression in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to find the `'&'` character in my string and switch it with `"and"` string using regular expression, but I am obviously doing it wrong.

This is a part of code that is checking if there is a `'&'` symbol and if there is one than it should change it to `"and"`.

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(toCheck, @"[^&]"))
   return Regex.Replace(toCheck, @"[^&]", "and");
```

What I am getting as outcome is string that contains only `'&'` symbols.
Can someone help me with this regular expression thing, it is a bit confusing to me. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any special reason to not using `.Replace("&", "and")` instead of regex?

Comment: The `Regex.Replace(toCheck, @"[^&]", "and");` replaces each character that is not `&` with `and`. The most confusing thing is that you have not provided any input and expected output.

Comment: @SonerGönül Actually there isn't any reason not to use .Replace haha I guess I've put myself in Regex mode when I've used it to check is there special character in string. Using only replace worked and it's kind of make code a bit cleaner. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just do it using regular string functions:

```
return toCheck.Replace("&","and");
```

If you really want to do it with regex, your function is a bit wrong, `[^&]` actually means **doesn't** contain `&`. Remove that and you'll be fine. It's not even necessary to put it between brackets as it's not a special character in regex. Just remember not to use regex for trivial things like searching one character and replacing it, it's using a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to check with IsMatch if you want to replace, it just won't replace if there are no occurences.

Also a simple string replace is enough, you do not need regexes for this to solve:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello&World&Mars".Replace("&", " and "));
```

This is enough

[^&] means *all characters that are not equal to `&`*.

^ inverts the selection

Answer (score 1):

This is how you'll perform a check on a string if it contains **'&'** Character in it!

```
      if(Regex.IsMatch(toCheck,@"[&]"))
        //do whatever you want to
```

although, there are many topics discussing Regex, you can visit any of them,  [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/939/An-Introduction-to-Regular-Expressions) i have got a link for you, you can learn Regular Expressions Briefly here!